# How to use only single NLog instance in whole DLL

Tags: c#, multithreading, nlog

I want to use NLog in DLL this is my code

```
namespace TestLogging
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public void foo()
        {
            LogWrapper.initlog();
            LogWrapper.write("Error message");
        }
    }


    public static class LogWrapper
    {
        private static bool isInit = false;
        private static Logger _logger = null;

        public static void initlog()
        {


            // Make sure logger is initialized only once 
            if (!isInit)
            {
                var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

                var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
                config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

                // Step 3. Set target properties 
                fileTarget.Layout = @"${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} - ${message}";
                fileTarget.FileName = "c:/myFolder/" + "${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log";

                var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
                config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

                // Step 5. Activate the configuration
                LogManager.Configuration = config;

                // Example usage
                _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");

                isInit = true;
            }
        }

        public static void write(string s)
        {
            if (isInit == false)
                throw new Exception("Not initialized");

            _logger.Error(s);

        }
    }
}
```

My goal is that many different classes in DLL should be able to use the NLog via this log wrapper. Configuration should be done once. Is my approach correctly implemented? Is it thread safe?

Comment: Yes i believe you are correct it is not thread safe.

Comment: @SeabizkitL Yeah so the point is how to fix it to suit my needs as I highlighted. and in what other ways is commonly NLog used? –

Comment: you will not have race conditions on initlog, You will have them on the actual physical file. I suggest you read up on it a bit more and then come back with a question. Set the initlog to a static constructor of the LogWrapper

Comment: @Seabizkit, depend how it is used, there is a potential race condition. better to be safe than sorry

Comment: you could fix your code, you cannot have non static method in a static class

Comment: @Seabizkit: "You will have them on the actual physical file" whyy??

Comment: @Fredou I have no clue what your on about, static constructors are only hit once... as the static class LogWapper is initialized*(don't tell me its not instantiated, i mean referenced by memory) first before any Write method is called from anywhere, so why? setup the NLog options every time..., this is not what he is wanting, therefore by having a static constructor on the static class you will not need a initlog() Method, therefore please explain yourself. further to this... just call it once in project initialize... and then call Write every other time. Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: @Fredou which then lends to what i was saying is the race conditions are in the Write.

Comment: @Seabizkit: I don't understand what you are saying why there is race in Write, is initlog is made threadsafe

Comment: @Fredou: Fixed methods

Comment: @Quser as, Write is the method you will be calling from different parts of the code, as this may be called from two different threads, they will fight for priority and bomb unless handled.

Comment: @Quser, how many times do you want to call initlog from anywhere in the code, and how many time do you want to call Write from anywhere in the code. What would make sense is to only call initlog once for the entire life time of the application and Write as many time as you like.

Comment: @Quser just remember!!!! big FYI Nlog is already thread safe. Researched this a while ago..... will the db write version... dont know about files... maybe  worth checking!

Comment: @Seabizkit, my comment about race condition with the initlog is only valid since the code and the content of the question doesn't mention any static constructor or how initlog will be called

Comment: @Fredou I appropriate that!, but that has nothing to do with what i was saying...The code in the Question is about what the questionnaire knows, it doesn't speak to how it can/should be implemented.

Comment: @Seabizkit: That is my point NLog is threadsafe while initlog not

Comment: @Quser mmm your sure NLog is thread safe for writing to files? I know it is for DB calls, as i researched that some time ago. The way he had his initlog, YES you are CORRECT! but again that was NOT what i was saying, and the response was in-context to me.

Answer (score 0):

declare a static object at the class level

```
private static object _locker = new object();
```

in the initlog put a lock on it

```
lock(_locker)
{
    //your code
}
```

in your write method do the same

```
    lock(_locker)
{
       if (isInit == false)
            throw new Exception("Not initialized");

        _logger.Error(s);

}
```

Comment: Why should I put lock in the write method, NLog is already thread safe by itself?

Comment: @Quser nlog might be thread safe but the if(isInit == false) isn't

Comment: Can you explain why here http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lock, approach you mention is not stated as completely thread safe, or I misunderstood this link? Also whole init method should go under lock? and should I use same _locker instance?